# How to change the alterrowcolor and Header Style using Lotus script?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

My requirement is, I am having a hundreds of views. I want to make them as standard colors and  UI. Simple I am using for changing the font color for column header and column values by NotesViewColumn class. But I do not know that which class is having the property for action bar and View alternate color and Heaer style and etc.,

In javascript is also welcome., But it should change its property as a designer level.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. The easiest one: Go and buy [ezView](http://www.ytria.com/WebSite.nsf/WebPageRequest/Solutions_viewEZen?OpenDocument&Lang=en) from Ytria. Should take you less than an hour to sort your views out
2. Create one view that looks the way you want your views to look and then go through all the views in a script, rename them, create a new view based on your view template and copy the view columns from the old views and adjust the view selection formulas (all in LotusScript)
3. Export your views in DXL and run some XSLT or search/replace to adjust the properties

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

I just ran this agent, to change all the views in my (small) test database to having alternate row colours, and it worked.

```
Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim exporter As NotesDXLExporter
Dim importer As NotesDXLImporter

Dim out As String
Dim infile As string
Dim pointer As long
Dim filenum As Integer
Dim altrow As integer


Dim unid As String
Dim doc As notesdocument
Set db = session.currentdatabase
Set exporter = session.Createdxlexporter
Set importer = session.Createdxlimporter

Dim count As Integer
count = 1
ForAll v In db.views
    unid = v.UniversalID
    Set doc = db.getdocumentbyunid(unid)
    out =  exporter.Export(doc)
    altrow = instr(out, "altrowcolor")
    If altrow > 0 Then
        pointer = InStr(altrow, out, "=")
        out = Left(out,pointer) & "'#f7f7f7'" & Mid(out, pointer+10)
    else
        pointer = InStr(out, "bgcolor=")
        pointer = InStr(pointer, out, " ")
        out = Left(out,pointer) & "altrowcolor='#f7f7f7' " & Mid(out, pointer+1)
    End if
    Call importer.setinput(out)
    Call importer.setoutput(db)
    importer.Designimportoption = 5
    importer.Documentimportoption = 5
    Call importer.Process()
    out = ""
    infile = ""
    count = count + 1
End ForAll
Print count & " views processed"
End Sub
```

If your view designs are much bigger, you might want to use a NotesStream instead of String for "out".  In that case, from the Help Files, I believe that the stream has to be closed and re-opened before you can use it for import.

For further research, I suggest writing "out" to a file, and examining the xml to find other "hidden" parameters.
Have fun, Phil

Answer (score 1):

I can also recommend ezView. Makes it a piece of cake to modify views. I also use actionBarEZ to modify action bars across applications.
I blogged about a few different development tools I use in Domino Designer, you can find the entry here: http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/texasswede/entry/mydevelopmenttools